# switch case avoid loop

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
int send_cmd( int sock, char * buffer, int lbuffer )
{
    int err = 0;

    //do_something part 1

while(1)
    switch(check_status(buffer)){
            case 1:
                return 0;
                 break;
            case 0:
                if (err > 0)
                    break;

                //do_something part 2

                err = 1;
            }
        return -1;
    }
```

I don't think this is well coded but I didn't know how to optimize it.

I wanna run the "part 2 code" only once and only if "part 1 code" gives an error.

***Can you tell me how to make it run correctly? Cause right now doesn't return anything after part 2 is executed once.***

Comment: This isn't clear.  Are you asking how to break out of both the switch statement and the while loop simultaneously?

Comment: Is the part 2 code  common for both cases in switch case?

Comment: case 1 is for an OK reply and case 0 is for error. In case of error I wanna execute command 2 but only once.

Comment: no, they are 2 different commands which I don't think are relevant. I just wanna know how to handle the switch case issue :P

Comment: Standard advices: compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g` on Linux), improve the code till no warnings are given, and use the debugger (e.g. `gdb` on Linux).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wanna run the "part 2 code" only once and only if "part 1 code" gives an error.

There's no need for a while loop or a switch statement.

```
// Do something part 1
if (check_status(buffer) == 1) {
   return 0;
}

// Do something part 2
if (check_status(buffer) == 1) {    
   return 0;
}
else {
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: @ShaMora considerably better in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the loop, you can just use an `if` and `return`. Since you don't use `err`, you can omit it as well.

```
// first command
int status = check_status(buffer);
if (status == 1)
    return 0;

// second command
status = check_status(buffer);
if (status == 1)
    return 0;

return -1;
```

At least in this simple case, `switch` is not better or faster than `if`. There might be cases, where this is true, but I won't bet on it. Usually, the optimizer is good enough to emit optimal machine code, whether you use switch or if. So go for the simple, readable and maintainable code.

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted to use switch because I read it's faster than if statement and better processed by the compiler. And besides I need that while loop. I have max 3 cases. 1. first command = ok; 2. first command = error, second command = ok; 3. first command error, second command error so ... exit. I don't know if I explained well :P

Comment: @ShaMora - *I read it's faster than if statement and better processed by the compiler* Nonsense. That *might* be true for a switch statement with many cases, but for a simple if/else versus a switch, that's not true. Besides, even if this was the case, you sill shouldn't replace clear and concise code with ugly and hard to understand code. It's called premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your, i think this is what you are trying to achieve using the `err` variable :

```
//Part 1
if ( check_status(buffer) ) return 0; //No error

//Part 2
if ( check_status(buffer) ) return 1; //One error
else return -1;  //Two errors
```

You dont need any while loops to do this.